# Access: grouping according to most recent date in a record (nested query)

Tags: sql, ms-access

**This Query on the table below**

```
SELECT ID, 
       Value, 
       As_of 
FROM Table a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, 
           MAX(As_of) AS As_of 
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY ID
) b 
ON a.ID=b.ID 
AND a.As_of = b.As_of
```

**Table:**

```
ID      Value  As_of
1173    156    20090601
1173    173    20081201
1173    307    20080901
1173    305    20080601
127     209    20090301
127     103    20081201
127     113    20080901
127     113    20080601
1271    166    20090201
1271    172    20081201
1271    170    20080901
1271    180    20080601
```

**Makes it look like this**

```
Result
ID      Value    As_of
1173    156      20090601
127     209      20090301
1271    166      20090201
```

It gets the MAX for the As_of for each ID and returns that... (from another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704260/access-sql-query-find-the-row-with-the-most-recent-date-for-each-distinct-entry) on stackoverflow)

I have basically the same table but not as a "physical table" but as a query result:

**Query:**

```
SELECT tblClassificationHistory.inmateID, 
       tblClassificationHistory.classificationID
FROM tblinmate 
INNER JOIN tblClassificationHistory 
ON tblinmate.inmateID = tblClassificationHistory.inmateID
GROUP BY tblClassificationHistory.inmateID, 
         tblClassificationHistory.classificationID,                
         tblClassificationHistory.reclassificationDate
ORDER BY tblClassificationHistory.inmateID;
```

**Makes this Result:**

```
inmateID    classificationID    reclassificationDate
2              3                       9/22/2015
2              4                       9/13/2015
2              8                       9/8/2015
3              8                       9/13/2015
4              4                       9/15/2015
4              8                       6/16/2015
5              3                       9/15/2015
5              4                       9/16/2015
5              8                       7/7/2015
6              8                       9/14/2015
7              7                       9/13/2015
8              3                       8/4/2015
8              8                       6/1/2015
9              3                       9/15/2015
10              6                       9/13/2015
11              3                       9/13/2015
12              3                       8/3/2015
12              4                       9/9/2015
12              6                       9/13/2015
12              8                       7/6/2015
13              8                       9/13/2015
14              8                       9/13/2015
15              4                       9/13/2015
16              4                       9/13/2015
17              8                       9/14/2015
18              8                       9/14/2015
19              3                       9/15/2015
```

I want to use "His" query in mine but after a few hours i cant...i presume its a subquery..but i cant for the life of me get the syntax right...

Result Im after: classificationID for Last date for each inmateID

```
inmateID    classificationID    reclassificationDate
2           3                   9/22/2015
3           8                   9/13/2015
4           4                   9/15/2015
5           4                   9/16/2015
6           8                   9/14/2015
7           7                   9/13/2015
8           3                   8/4/2015
9           3                   9/15/2015
10          6                   9/13/2015
11          3                   9/13/2015
12          6                   9/13/2015
13          8                   9/13/2015
14          8                   9/13/2015
15          4                   9/13/2015
16          4                   9/13/2015
17          8                   9/14/2015
18          8                   9/14/2015
19          3                   9/15/2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.inmateID,
       a.classificationID,
       b.max_date
FROM (
    SELECT tblClassificationHistory.inmateID, 
           tblClassificationHistory.classificationID,                
           tblClassificationHistory.reclassificationDate
    FROM tblinmate
    INNER JOIN tblClassificationHistory
    ON tblinmate.inmateID = tblClassificationHistory.inmateID 
) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tblClassificationHistory.inmateID, 
           MAX(tblClassificationHistory.reclassificationDate) as max_date
    FROM tblinmate
    INNER JOIN tblClassificationHistory
    ON tblinmate.inmateID = tblClassificationHistory.inmateID
    GROUP BY tblClassificationHistory.inmateID  
) b
ON a.inmateID = b.inmateID
AND a.reclassificationDate = b.max_date
ORDER BY a.inmateID;
```

You can break it down into two subqueries (`a` and `b`). In `b`, we'll find the MAX date in our table, excluding classificationID and grouping only by inmateID. We'll wind up with a table like this:

```
+----------+-----------+
| inmateID | max_date  |
+----------+-----------+
| 2        | 9/22/2015 |
| 3        | 9/13/2015 |
| 4        | 9/15/2015 |
| 5        | 9/16/2015 |
| 6        | 9/14/2015 |
| 7        | 9/13/2015 |
| ...      | ...       |
+----------+-----------+
```

In `a`, we'll simply grab the unaggregated values, including classificationID this go-around:

```
+----------+------------------+----------------------+
| inmateID | classificationID | reclassificationDate |
+----------+------------------+----------------------+
| 2        | 3                | 9/22/2015            |
| 2        | 4                | 9/13/2015            |
| 2        | 8                | 9/15/2015            |
| 3        | 8                | 9/16/2015            |
| 4        | 4                | 9/14/2015            |
| 4        | 8                | 9/13/2015            |
| ...      | ...              | ...                  |
+----------+------------------+----------------------+
```

We join the two subqueries, finding rows in `a` where reclassificationDate is equal to the MAX date with just calculated in `b`. We can then grab the appropriate classificationID from those joined rows to build our final table.

Comment: maybe its my Access....but i get a syntax error after i paste it in and try to run it...suntax error in FROM clause

Comment: Ha, I put a period where a comma should be. I fixed it, go ahead and give it another crack.

Comment: Still syntax error in FROM clause...added INNER to the Join and then no error but....i get tblClassifiedHistory.inmateID could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause...maybe because I added the INNER?

Comment: It was the ORDER BY. I had the wrong table name. It's edited, give it another shot!

Comment: PERFECT! it works after I add the INNER to the join ;)

Comment: Updated the answer so we can wink together.

Comment: I have to say...i am mighty impressed with the speeeeeed of you guys...or maybe its just you Andrew hehe i will definitely keep coming back here..

Comment: sorry..not sure where or how to post this..you see i simplified my table relations and now after i got my answer im getting double vision trying to integrate your beautifully crafted SQL code...should I make a new question or add an answer or post it here in the comments...?

Comment: The SO community thanks you for asking! What do you mean by "simplified my table relations"? Does it dramatically change the code?

Comment: Depends on your definition of dramatically...the structure i pasted in was two tables...but im actually getting personal detail fields from a tblPerson related to tblInmates on a key (personID) and then i have another table (tblSquadHistory) that has the same structure as the tblClassificationHistory meaning im searching for the most recent date etc..

Comment: Phew, alrighty, well since you've already accepted an answer, you probably shouldn't change the scope of the question. I'd say just post another question if you need to. Do you understand the code I posted well enough to edit it? I suppose I probably should've included some explanation in my answer...

Comment: Sorry for this (im new to posting these kind of questions)..i thought it would be to much code to paste into one question..well editing code i do so by testing hehe but i have never come across this a. and b. creating some temp tables i assume..so that's a little hard...but ill post another question and link this one to it...thx

Comment: Ok, let me add some explanation first. I probably should anyway. Meanwhile, you can check out [this link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/subqueries-in-sql-server/) to learn about subqueries in SQL Server.

Comment: I added a pretty detailed explanation to my answer that might help you to edit the query as you need. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok great i read through the link you gave me..very interesting with these nested Querys ill try to see if i can make heads or tails of it...i added a new Question too...maybe you can have a look at it and just slap me in the face for my ignorance or say its not that big of a deal :)

Comment: Please Andrew have a quick look at my other Question i have restructured it to make it look better. I am reading all kinds of tuts but i cant make it work...sorry for stalking you..